# Looking for a shurtcut of Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#, winforms, shortcut, properties.settings

The more options I have defined, the more a have to type when I have to modify them. So I'm looking for a shorter version of Properties.Settings.Default.varX

I tried:

```
Properties.Settings settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
settings.var1 = "x";
settings.var2 = "y";
settings.var3 = "Z";
Properties.Settings.Default = settings;
```

but Properties.Settings.Default is read-only and the Save function has no overload.

So is there any other way than typing Properties.Settings.Default again and again?

Comment: If you want to save some typing time, you could just copy and paste. Using hacky ways could just make your code messier.

Comment: A "using YourApp.Properties;" in your source could reduce to "var xy = Settings.Default"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just try it like this:

```
Properties.Settings settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
settings.var1 = "x";
settings.var2 = "y";
settings.var3 = "Z";
settings.Save();
```

Comment: Because `Properties.Settings` is a class, `settings` actually contains the same reference to `Properties.Settings.Default`. Changing properties to `settings` is equivalent to changing `Properties.Settings.Default`.

Comment: @AlvinWong Isn't that what he wants?

Answer (score 3):

To shorten a little bit what you have to type you might try adding this to the initial using statements

```
using MyProps = <your_namespace>.Properties.Settings;
```

and then in code you could use

```
MyProps.Default.Var1 = "";
```

`<your_namespace>` should be replaced by the full namespace where the settings are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Something I use that I find quite handy is the following:

```
var props = Properties.Settings.Default;
```

This way, if I type "props", it counts as if I have typed "Properties.Settings.Default".
So I can type now

> props.Name

instead of

> Properties.Settings.Default.Name